# Recovering deleted download

Tags: ps4, psn

I accidentally clicked "Cancel and Delete" on my PS4 download. It was so close to being finished and now I have to restart the download from the beginning. is there anyway I can get that downloaded data back?

Answer (score 6):

No.

The action performed stated the functional outcome and there is no way to recover the deleted portion.